# How to crop a round image with transparent background?

Tags: css, paint.net

I am currently working on a site. I want to create custom radio buttons. The background of the website is an image. So I want the radio button to seamlessly integrate with this background image. I have created the radio button and every time I crop it on paint.net, it comes out with a square black background. The image is saved as a GIF. How can I remove the black background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your level of experience or which software is available at your disposal. But a fast answer would be to use a format hat supports transparency.

So you make sure the area around the circle is transparent then export your image as a PNG 24bit with transparency.

It could be done by Photoshop easily not sure how to do it with paint.net.

Let me know

Comment: Thanks. Not so sharp in Photoshop - I use Paint.net... But then also not so sharp in that too. Will give it a go a try to pick up some Photoshop skills. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the save as button and select PNG.